# Difference between USB upstream and downstream ends

Tags: usb

I'm doing a custom mobile robot project which utilizes Raspberry Pi, Arduino and I want to grasp the concept of the USB standard (http://www.usb.org/home).
When reading about USB cables I've encountered the distinction between 'upstream' and 'downstream' connectors (https://computer.howstuffworks.com/usb1.htm) which is supposed to prevent any mistakes of connecting the wrong end of the cable to PC/printer etc.

So here comes my question: Why there is a distinction between the upstream and downstream if the data can flow in both directions?

If I connect my printer & scanner to my PC, I can print a document using the printer from my PC (so data flows from PC to printer) but then I can scan a document on my printer and save it on PC (data flow from Scanner to PC) so it seems that the one side can be downstream or upstream.

Comment: Because only the USB host arbitrates the bus. It's under complete control of the host.

Comment: "*...Arduino and I want to...*", it is sentient?!

Comment: The purpose is not to prevent you from connecting a cable "the wrong way" between a USB host and a USB device. The purpose is to prevent you from trying to connect a host to a host or, a device to a device.

Comment: You need to go to your link, to dev elopers section, http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/ , download USB 3.2 zip file, and read the basic USB 2.0 specification, at least its introductory part if you want to grasp the USB concept.